# SQL Server : Over Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I am trying to get to grips with using the function `Partition` to generate results, unfortunately I am dealing with someone else table design that has no primary key and I am not able to add one "terrible I know"

My sample code as below

```
CREATE TABLE mytable  (OrderNo varchar(20), TaskNo int, Hours Decimal(2))

insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0001',1)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0002',2)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0002',2)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0002',2)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0003',0)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0004',0)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0005',0)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0006',0)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0007',4)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0007',4)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0007',4)
insert into mytable values ('GNR68003327','0007',4)
```

I know I could just use a distinct to get the following results but in this instance I am going to be better of using Partition due to this being only an example of what I am trying to do so there is some more to go with this.

What I want to do is return the first value of the `Hours` column at every `TaskNo` change so the results should be

```
OrderNo     TaskNo  Hours 
GRN68003327 0001    1
GRN68003327 0002    2
GRN68003327 0003    0
GRN68003327 0004    0
GRN68003327 0005    0
GRN68003327 0006    0
GRN68003327 0007    4
```

I think it should look something like this but I just cant get the required results

```
SELECT 
    OrderNo, TaskNo, 
    First_Value(Hours) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY TaskNo) 
FROM 
    mytable
```

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Thanks Phil

Comment: I assume you're using SQL 2012 since you're using the `First_Value` function?  If so then the SQL 2008 tag doesn't apply.

Comment: Hi Stanley, yes I am using SQL Server 2012, thanks P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by orderno, taskno order by ??) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Notice the `??` in the query.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no first or last row within a set.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.  Whatever that column is, use it for the `??`.

Comment: Hi Gordon,  Thanks for the reply and that was spot on thank you very much for the answer. P

Answer (score 1):

You have to partition by `TaskNo` *and* `OrderNo` to get the results you want.  Since you don't have any meaningful way to order the rows within those partitions you can just order by `TaskNo`, but there's no guarantee that you'll get the same "first" record every time without some sort of indicator of order:

```
SELECT OrderNo, 
       TaskNo, 
       First_Value(Hours) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo , TaskNo ORDER BY TaskNo) 
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thanks also for the answer D